# There was an error loading preference bundle for XXX?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, preference, tweak

I did a simple tweak with PreferenceBundle. The PrefBundle works nice on non-ARM64, but on ARM64 it says "there was an error loading preference bundle for nameTweak".

I tried to add at the top of the Makefile:`export ARCHS = armv7 arm64` But this not resolved the problem.

Someone know how to fix it?

P.S: I tried to move the files from "Library/PreferencesBundle/XXX.bundle" to "Library/PreferencesLoader/Preferences" and in this way I can see The options in Settings>XXX, but I can't see the links, popup ecc because they aren't allowed in the PreferenceLoader

Comment: why are you using a Makefile and not Xcode?

Comment: Because I'm using theos, I always use it (so I don't know how to use xCode)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the export out of the line, so that it's just `ARCHS = armv7 arm64`, and make sure that you are building against the iOS 7 SDK (which, if the only SDK available is iOS 7, is what theos should be building against)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem months ago.

There are 2 way to do it:

1) Use xCode

2) Update preferences header if you are using theos

But in both way you have to add

```
ARCHS = armv7 arm64
```

In the Bundle Makefile